# Can we use RDD data Filter like RDD.filter(x => x.NOT startswith("XX")

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Do we have any method in Spark/Scala for filtering those data which not `Startswith("XX")` like `RDD.filter(x => x.startsWith("XX")` but my requirement is to filter those records which not starts with `"XX"`.

```
val custRDD = sc.textFile("D:\\CCA175\\Navdeep\\spark-dataset\\spark-dataset\\problem2\\customer.txt")
val wordRDD = custRDD.flatMap(x=>x.split(',')).filter(x => (x.startsWith("XX") && x.endsWith("XX")))
```

**But I want to filter those records which not starts with/ ends with "XX"**

Comment: Have you tried `!x.startsWith("XX")` and `!x.endsWith("XX")`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.filter(x => !(x.startsWith("XX") && x.endsWith("XX")))
```

It's unfortunate that Spark, AFAIK, hasn't added `filterNot` to the RDD API (it's in the Scala collections API, which Spark generally takes after). You can add that operation via an implicit:

```
object RDDEnhancements {
  implicit class Ops[A](val underlying: RDD[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def filterNot(pred: A => Boolean): RDD[A] = underlying.filter(a => !pred(a))
  }
}
```

Then in any code where you want the `filterNot` operation available

```
import RDDEnhancements._
```